# При запуске селениум не запускает браузер?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, chromedriver

Что делать не работает селениум у меня не на одном браузере. При запуске селениум не запускает браузер? Ошибок не показывает, только висит типа бесконечный цикл даже если в программе скрипте нету циклов.

На хроме такая ошибка при всех драйвер версиях

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 90
> Current browser version is 89.0.4389.90 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

или просто открывается и закрываетс резко.

А *firefox*  у меня тупа висит(версия драйвера 29.0 версия firefox 88.0 beta(пробывал драйвер 28 было норм, потом начал просто висеть на днях , сменил на 29 ,выдавало ошибку с 29 и 87, обновил свой 87 на 88 тож фигня осталось висит )),(устанавливал темы и пару расширений прокси и рекапча  в оригинал)
даже ie не запускается. Что делать?

п.с. скрипты рабочие, но теперь вообще не работаю.
п.п.с понял почему не подключает через оптимус у меня стоит 90 браузер а он каким-то образом считает 89 браузер для подключения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зделай так будет 100% работать такая ошибка у всех случаетца.
Внизу код
"""from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='C:/python/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
"""

> https://overcoder.net/q/918223/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80-chrome-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-chromedriver-%D0%B2-python
> Помогает только так подключать...

Comment: Странно но работает вот этот вариант .Пасиб!!!

Answer (score 2):

А вы читали что у вас в исключении написано?

> This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 90 Current browser version is 89.0.4389.90 with binary path

У вас ChromeDriver для Сhrome версии 90, но на пк установлен Chrome 89. Либо обновите Chrome до версии 90, либо установите ChromeDriver для версии 89.

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver.exe закинь в одну попку со скриптом .py в скрипте укажи путь в webdriver.exe

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")

Comment: Делал все равно  такая ошибка возникает.